# adjust radgrid edit inplace height of items

Tags: telerik, height, edit, radgrid, items

I have a simple problem. When in edit mode, my radgrid edit inplace is not showing cleanly/clearly.  I mean its big. I need it to be small.

BEFORE EDIT.

[image]. While editing it becomes big, like this.[image]
I need it to be if possible make 'AK' little higher and update and cancel buttons also little higher. My radgrid width is 250px. I did vertical-align:top; but no change in output. How to solve this? IF you need more info, please ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your edit form looks a bit strange. Probably you need to make the radgrid slightly wider to get it right also on the edit form. However, a solution that allows you to make the editform as you need and like is to use  an edit form template. References on how to achieve it can be found [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/form-template-update/defaultcs.aspx). Alternatively post your markup and you will get more accurate answers.

Comment: Thanks. I found an issue with my layout there. There were 2 validators below the text boxes (required and compare). They occupied that place. Once I removed them and modified my validation logic it was much cleaner.